# setEmptyView on ListView not working

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to set empty view when the listView is empty. This is my full XML Layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/fondgris"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Header  Starts -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/head"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="35sp"
        android:background="@layout/header_gradient"
        android:paddingBottom="5dip"
        android:paddingTop="5dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:text="List of projects"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:tint="#0E5EC7" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/logout"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp "
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:onClick="logout"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/sortie"
            android:tint="#FFFFFF" >
        </ImageButton>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/home"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp "
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/logout"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:onClick="home"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/home" >
        </ImageButton>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp "
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/home"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:onClick="back"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/back"
            android:tint="#FFFFFF" >
        </ImageButton>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- Editext and ImageView for Search -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bnSearch"
            android:hint="Search..."
            android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/bnSearch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/inputSearch"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bnClear"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/search" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/bnClear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/inputSearch"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dip"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:onClick="ClearSearch"
            android:src="@drawable/cancel" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonAddProject"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/add"
            android:onClick="addProject"
            android:text=" Add Project"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- List View -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="337dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.74" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emptyList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Liste vide "
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.04"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bnPrevious"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:text="&lt;&lt; Prev"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/page"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Page"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editpage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/of"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="of "
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nbpage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bnNext"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:text="Next >>"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

It has no effect, I did debugging and it enter in if part but without setting the list to empty, the list continue to appear ! I can't understand why, I appreciate your help.

```
final ProjectContainer container = gson.fromJson(resultat,
                    ProjectContainer.class);
            final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            TextView emptyList = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.emptyList);
            // if list empty
            if (container == null) {
                lv.setEmptyView(emptyList);
                emptyList.setText("No Projects Found");

            }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure `container == null`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1. Use RelativeLayout
2. Add your emptyList view first
3. Add you listView (emptyList must be right behind the listview)
4. If you got 0 items from json, set the visibility of listView to View.INVISIBLE.

**Edit:**

Ok, you need to change your XML a little bit.

enclose emptyList and list inside a RelativeLayout as follow.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emptyList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="There is no item"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list" android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

To show empty text, set listView visibility to GONE.
Here is sample output on my side.
First with listView visibility Visible and 2nd is with listview visibility GONE

[image][image]

Here if your full updated xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/fondgris"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Header  Starts -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/head"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="35sp"
        android:background="@layout/header_gradient"
        android:paddingBottom="5dip"
        android:paddingTop="5dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:text="List of projects"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:tint="#0E5EC7" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/logout"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp "
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:onClick="logout"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/sortie"
            android:tint="#FFFFFF" >
        </ImageButton>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/home"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp "
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/logout"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:onClick="home"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/home" >
        </ImageButton>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp "
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/home"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:onClick="back"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/back"
            android:tint="#FFFFFF" >
        </ImageButton>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- Editext and ImageView for Search -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bnSearch"
            android:hint="Search..."
            android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/bnSearch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/inputSearch"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bnClear"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/search" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/bnClear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/inputSearch"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dip"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:onClick="ClearSearch"
            android:src="@drawable/cancel" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonAddProject"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/add"
            android:onClick="addProject"
            android:text=" Add Project"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- List View -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="337dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.74" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/emptyList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="There is no item"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list" android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >
        </ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>
   <!-- end of listview -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.04"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bnPrevious"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:text="&lt;&lt; Prev"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/page"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Page"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editpage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/of"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="of "
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nbpage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bnNext"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:text="Next >>"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And in code.

```
if (container == null) {
         lv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Hope it will be useful.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I updated my question, you can found the full layout, I tried to set set visibility of listView to View.INVISIBLE but the textview(emptyList) still not showing.

Comment: I did that too, the text of emptyList is not displaying at all

Comment: @Adnan Thank you but I want to set the textview in the code    emptyList.setText("No Projects Found"); but it is not showing even when I updated my layout as you mentioned

Comment: It works now I added emptyList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); I don't khow why it was invisible but I'm happy now after hours of madness. Thank you very much, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Encapsulating ListView and the empty view inside RelativeLayout solved my issues

Comment: I don't think the layout matters. It works for me when I use LinearLayout. The trick for me was the order of the views

Answer (score 17):

Below a snippet with an example

```
TextView emptyList = new TextView(getContext());
emptyList.setText("The list is empty");

ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
((ViewGroup)mListView.getParent()).addView(emptyList);
mListView.setEmptyView(emptyList);
mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: This is somewhat similar to what Adnan said above. Its just that this is done in code and he has mentioned the emptyview in the xml. This will work even if you remove mListView.setEmptyView(emptyList); from the code.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to do a null check before setting the empty view.. Simply set the emptyview to the ListView. List view will take care of showing the empty view when the adapter is passed with zero contents.

```
            lv.setEmptyView(emptyList);
            emptyList.setText("No Projects Found");
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have to do a null check because I have a have the case when the container is not null.But I still can't figure out why the list don't become empty to showing the textview.

Comment: You also want to make sure what 'Justin Muller' had mentioned in his answer. You need an adapter for this to work. Otherwise go with Adnan's answer.

Comment: I like this solution better than setting visibility of the empty view.

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling `setEmptyView(View)` before `setAdapter(ListAdapter)`?

I think the order of these operations is important (`setEmptyView` must be called first), and that an adapter must be set for the empty view to be displayed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I'm calling lv.setAdapter(adaptateur) in the else part. Why would I call an adapter to set the List view to empty when I want it to show only the textview

Comment: In order for the empty view to be shown, an empty adapter needs to be set.  Confusing, but that is just the way Android works!  This sentiment seems to be echoed by @Doctor Drive

Answer (score -1):

Calling to setEmptyView will not make your list empty. It sets a View which the ListView show if it's Adapter is empty.
Thus, after setEmptyView you must set Adapter which has no items in it.

Answer (score -1):

When you have a layout which has a ListView and below it a RelativeLayout with GraphicsButtons for Icons such as delete etc, then the method I use to get the ListView to take up all but the bottom bit of the screen is (as I found out from this site) to have its height set at 0px and a weight of 1 plus leaving the other Views/RelativeLayouts with no weights.  All well and good until you first show an empty ListView after which it doesn't appear again because even though it has items in it later on, its height was set on its first appearance.

I show the little bit of code (no Layouts included) that I use to get the bloody thing working…

```
public void listFiles() {
    boolean mEmptyList;
    mFileNames = mFile.list();
    mFileCount = (mFileNames == null) ? 0 : mFileNames.length;
    mEmptyList = (mFileCount == 0);
    mFileChecked = mEmptyList ? null : new boolean[mFileCount];
    View mEmpty;
    if ((mEmpty = mListView.getEmptyView()) != null) {
        if (mEmpty.getVisibility() != ( mEmptyList ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE )) {
            mEmpty.setVisibility( mEmptyList ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE );
            if (mFileCount > 0)
                mListView.setMinimumHeight(((ViewGroup) mListView.getParent()).getHeight());
            mListView.setVisibility( mEmptyList ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE );
        }
    }
}
```

If this isn't in the constructor of the adapter then one then has to call

```
mListView.invalidateViews();
```