# setEmptyView not working on ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

So I have a `ListView` in a `Fragment` on which I run `listView.setEmptyView(getActivity().findViewById(R.id.emptyListView));`

In my xml file I have

```
  <ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView_main" />

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Nothing here yet! "
    android:id="@+id/emptyListView"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

The `ListView` works fine when there is data but  the `TextView` does not show up when it is empty. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16862450/603270

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd verify that the findViewById() returns non-null.

Try .findViewById() on the fragment's root view.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It was indeed returning null and the reason was because I was running .findViewById on the Activity instead of the rootView.